# how to make the three li content auto show and hide one by one with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Supposed the html code is:

```
<div class="scroller">
          <ul class="header-contact">
            <li id="header-section1" class="sectionslide"><p>We offer FREE shipping</p><p>on orders of $50 or more!</p></li>
            <li id="header-section2" class="sectionslide"><p>We ship your orders same day</p><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;if ordered before 2pm PST.</p></li>
            <li id="header-section3" class="sectionslide"><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Call Us: 1234</p><p>Our hours: Mon - Fri 10am-5pm</p></li>
          </ul>
          </div>
```

i want to make the  li content auto show and hide one by one. i am sorry. i don't know how to set the time duration to make the li content show and hide. which event i should do?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Have you got any vague ideas how you want to approach the situation? If yes (to either answer), include them in your question to show *some* effort.

Comment: look on http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/, example http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/nowrap2.html

Comment: thank you,but i want to do it with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zqGLW/)):

```
// starting a named function expression
// the function name is only usable inside the function scope
(function slide(wrapper, slides, idx, delay, duration) {

  // delay an animation on the wrapper element
  $(wrapper).delay(delay || 1000).animate({

    // moving the wrapper element upwards by the slide element top position
    top: -$(slides).eq(idx || 0).position().top

  // setting animation duration and anonymous callback function
  }, duration || 1000, function () {

    // calling slide recursively, but incrementing or resetting the
    // passed slide element index
    slide(wrapper, slides, idx < slides.length - 1 ? idx + 1 : 0, delay, duration);
  });

// closing the function body and immediately call it, with parameters for
// the wrapper element,
// the slide elements,
// the index to start with,
// the animation delay and
// the animation duration
}($('.scroller > ul'), $('.scroller > ul > li'), 0, 1500, 500));
```

Comment: i am sorry, i can't follow your code well. where is the document.ready() function

Comment: There is none, you would have to place that code inside your ready function.

Comment: i am sorry, i am still can't follow your code well.could you explain it with more details. many thanks,

Comment: there is no code to invoke the function slide, why it can run?

Comment: I added some code hints, hope it helps. If you have problems understanding why the function works, you should probably read up on javascript in general. A good start would be: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

```
var delay = 0;
var interval = 1000;

jQuery('.sectionslide').css('display','none');
jQuery('.header-contact li').each(function() {


    jQuery(this).delay(delay).fadeIn();
    delay += interval;


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nQAUH/

Comment: thank you, the effect is not i want, i want when the fist li shows, the rest are all hide, the second shows, the rest are all hidden

Comment: thank you,but i want to do it with code. it there a simple way to get it by a little code?

Comment: Check @Yoshi's Answer, it's what you want

Answer (score 0):

I would use a plugin called cycle,

because this has alot of different effects and you can also manage the pages, 
and basically alot bug-free than doing it yourself and wasting alot of time for something that is already done for you.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

are the demos, if you should need help installing it.